# Powershell v2 & v3 hangs with use of group-object in combination with import-csv

Tags: powershell, grouping

When I used the line of script it seems to crash the ISE of powershell. If I remove all but the first 25 lines of the file I can count them without issue. However, reading the entire file 90,000 lines will cause the powershell ISE to never complete the command and then if I press the stop button the ISE will never respond (although I can close the application).

```
import-CSV C:\CONVERT\DataOutput.csv -Delimiter '|' | group-object 'Person ID'
| measure-Object 'Name'
```

I've noticed that when I run the import-csv command the private working set memory climbs well to about 2.9 GB. I've reviewed the command options and don't see a way to handle the object in memory in a different manner, The import-csv will complete on it's own but it doesn't when run in combination with Group-object & measure-object. Thanks in advance for any thoughts or questions to help me find the path!

Comment: The file is 66mb, while I feel this is large for a csv file, it doesn't seem huge for a modern system. Since office can open it I feel like powershell should be able to work with the file.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove measure-object, does it run all the way? Performance tip, try to add the -noelement switch to group-object, it should boost execution and reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Shay, Thank you for the suggestion however running it without the measure-object seems to hang (I've let it run for about 20 minutes without a response). This is with the -noelement flag added.

Comment: Does this do any good? import-csv ... | foreach {$_."person id"} | group -noel

Comment: Your version took almost two hours to complete. It didn't give me the result I was looking for but it did shed light on the possible problem. It appears the import-csv function is not parsing the Line Feeds correctly, this is due to the fields having LFs within them in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Make sure the CSV file is formatted correctly, obviously, LFs inside fields is not a normal csv structure.